# I want to count a count inside of a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I'm using this code to try to get the number of parcels that have multiple imps inside a neigh.

```
SELECT r.neighbhood
    ,count(CASE 
            WHEN count(p.repropkey > 1)
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS 'Multiple Imps'
FROM realprop r
LEFT JOIN reprop p ON r.realkey = p.realkey
WHERE r.fmvres > 0
GROUP BY r.neighbhood
```

Comment: If you have a question, it is not clear from your question.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! please edit your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are nesting `count()`s.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT r.neighbhood,
       (CASE WHEN count(p.repropkey > 1) THEN 1
        END) AS Multiple_Imps
FROM realprop r LEFT JOIN
     reprop p
     ON r.realkey = p.realkey
WHERE r.fmvres > 0
GROUP BY r.neighbhood
```